# CLGeocoder not returning neighborhood name when I reversegeocode

Tags: core-location, cllocationmanager, reverse-geocoding, clgeocoder

I am currently working on an app that will use the data returned by reversegeocode. Right now I can successfully receive the following values for a location: address, city, state, zip code, and country. In addition to the values that I am able to get, I would also like to  obtain the name of the neighborhood for the locations that I reversegeocode. My code is as follows:

```
CLLocationManager *location = [[CLLocation alloc] init];
[location setDelegate:self];
location.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
location.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;

[location startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

CLGeocoder *geolocation = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
NSLog(@"Update method is definitely being called!");
NSLog(@"Your current location is : %@", [locations lastObject]);
[geolocation reverseGeocodeLocation:[locations lastObject] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Reverse geocode complete: %@", placemarks);

    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"The locality area is: %@", placemark.locality);
}];
}
```

I expected placemark.locality to return the neighborhood but it returns the city instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation Apple has for the `CLPlacemark` class, I noticed that there were a few fields that I was unaware of.

Inclusive in these fields is exactly what I was trying acquire, the subLocality, which seems to be Apple documentation for neighborhood. If I had just read the documentation instead of assuming the object returned from `[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]`, when stored in `CLPlacemark` *placemark, would have no more data than what is shown when `NSLog(@"%@", [placemarks objectAtIndex:0])` is called, I would have figured this out much sooner. Oh well. The code I used to access the neighborhood is:

```
[placemark subLocality];
```